# pandas rolling apply with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I can't understand the behaviour of `pandas.rolling.apply` with `np.prod` and NaNs. E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2013-01-05'))
```

Gives this dataframe:

```
            B   C
2013-01-01  1.0 1
2013-01-02  1.0 2
2013-01-03  2.0 3
2013-01-04  NaN 4
2013-01-05  4.0 5
```

If I `apply` the numpy `np.prod` function to a 3 day rolling window with `raw=False` and `min_periods=1` it works as expected, ignoring the NaNs.

```
df.rolling('3D', min_periods=1).apply(np.prod, raw=False)

            B   C
2013-01-01  1.0 1.0
2013-01-02  1.0 2.0
2013-01-03  2.0 6.0
2013-01-04  2.0 24.0
2013-01-05  8.0 60.0
```

However with `raw=True` I get NaNs in column B:

```
df.rolling('3D', min_periods=1).apply(np.prod, raw=True)

            B   C
2013-01-01  1.0 1.0
2013-01-02  1.0 2.0
2013-01-03  2.0 6.0
2013-01-04  NaN 24.0
2013-01-05  NaN 60.0
```

I'd like to use `raw=True` for speed, but I don't understand this behavior? Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: If `raw=False`, pd will ignore all NaNs in the window (here a 3-day window) when applying the rolling function (here np.prod) so you don't get NaN for the last two entries. If `raw=True`, pd will simply apply the numpy function to the window without ignoring NaN, causing the last two entries to be NaN since their windows include NaN.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You can try this code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def foo(x):
    return np.prod(x, where=~np.isnan(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
                      index=pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2013-01-05'))
    res = df.rolling('3D', min_periods=1).apply(foo, raw=True)
    
    print(res)
```

```
             B     C
2013-01-01  1.0   1.0
2013-01-02  1.0   2.0
2013-01-03  2.0   6.0
2013-01-04  2.0  24.0
2013-01-05  8.0  60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @padu and @bui for contributing comments/answers to lead me to the answer I was looking for, namely explaining the different behaviors.

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) points out, when calling rolling `apply` with `raw=False`, each window is converted to a pandas.Series before being passed to `np.prod`. With `raw=True` each window is converted to a numpy array.

The key observation then is that `np.prod` behaves differently on a Series compared to an ndarray, ignoring the NaN in the Series case, and this is why we get different behaviors:

`np.prod(np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 3]))` gives `nan`

`np.prod(pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, 3]))` gives `6.0`

It's not clear to me why the NaN is ignored for the Series, but as @bui points out, you can ignore the NaNs for the ndarray case by setting the `where` keyword to `np.prod`.